# Labels perpendicular to a c

Tags: rotating, labels

I am new to all this. I intend to make scales some of which are curved. I would like to have the tick marks and the corresponding numbers erected **perpendicularly** to a given 2D curve, e.g. a circle - think of the face of a clock.  How can I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not doing anything proper today!

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,x11names]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [fill=Goldenrod!30] (2,0)arc[radius=2cm,start angle=0,end angle=180] -- (-2,0) -- cycle;
\fill[IndianRed3] (0.1,0)arc[radius=0.1cm,start angle=0,end angle=180] -- (-0.1,0) -- cycle;
\foreach \angle/\label in {10/1,20/2,30/3,40/4,50/5,60/6,70/7,80/8,90/9,100/10,110/11,120/12,130/13,140/14,150/15,160/16,170/17}{
\draw (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\path (\angle:1.7cm)  -- node[rotate=\angle-90,pos=0.02,font=\tiny]{\textsf{\label}}(\angle:2cm);
}
\foreach \angle in {1,2,...,179}{
\draw[thin] (\angle:1.9cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
}
\draw[IndianRed3, thick] (0,0) -- (68:1.6cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the path you can use the `sloped` option to put the node perpendicular to path.
For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[allow upside down]
\draw (0,2) arc (90:-270:2) node foreach \p in {1,...,12} [pos=\p/12,below,sloped] {\p};
\draw (0,2) arc (90:-270:2) node foreach \p in {1,...,12} [pos=\p/12,sloped] {\tikz\draw (0,0)--(0,1ex);};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]